# Bluetooth Thermal Printer with SDK

Tags: printer

I am working on an online ordering platform for retail businesses. The platform will allow customers to create their order on our platform and then pick up and pay for the order in-store. We are in need of a preferably bluetooth thermal printer that has an SDK that we can hook into so that the orders that are placed on our platform print out automatically at the store.

Comment: An SDK? What for? I mean, text/graphics can be sent to virtually *every* printer using the default functionality provided by the operating system, isn't it?

Comment: I am assuming I need an SDK so that we can develop webhooks on our platform to automatically print the order details at each store.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're talking about. So you want a printer which will register for Webhooks notifications and print something whenever it receives an event. Makes sense, so +1. Not sure if such thing exists, however. And, moreover, wouldn't it be just so easier (and flexible) to have on your LAN a machine running a script which would listen to Webhooks and dispatch orders to the printer? It seems like a few hours job, and would make it possible to use *any* printer.